# Wifi hotspot software package other than ap-hotspot?

Tags: wireless, ap-hotspot

I have tried using `ap-hotspot` to create a wifi-hotspot but it gives me some `problem every time` I use it . I just want to ask is there any **other software  package** that create a wifi-hotspot `othen than ap-hotspot` ?

Answer (score 3):

I really like create_ap and it's very lightweight.

```
git clone https://github.com/oblique/create_ap
cd create_ap/
sudo make install
```

To create your hotspot just run the command

```
create_ap wlp2s0 wlp2s0 MyHotspot Mypassword
```

And that's all there is to it! (Note in my case the same device is used to transmit & receive - but if you're using two different cards just use those instead)

Comment: `ERROR: Your adapter can not be a station (i.e. be connected) and an AP at the same time`

Answer (score 1):

Here are two I found on Google:

[Create a WiFi Hotspot 1](http://sourcedigit.com/13678-create-wifi-hotspot-ubuntu-14-04-android-support/)

[Create a WiFi Hotspot 2](http://infostandpoint.com/create-wifi-hotspot-on-ubuntu-14-04/)

Google Search: 
`hotspot software for ubuntu -ap-hotspot`

There are still some using ap-hotspot, but there are others that do not. Also, there are a number of YouTube videos.