# Windows 10-like hotspot program for Ubuntu

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, router, hot-spot

[Windows 10 Mobile Hotspot setup](https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/71072/windows-10-tip-setup-mobile-hotspot)

I need to create something like the above in Ubuntu to connect my chromecast in my dorm room. It basically re-routes the wifi connection. This seems to be impossible in Ubuntu so far based on my research. Can you guide me regarding this topic:

Mobile hotspot wifi to wifi in Ubuntu...

Comment: See [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/927008/300665) any easy way to do it with one wifi adapter just check `iwconfig` to see what you need to use for the command

Answer (score 0):

Sharing a connection has long been a feature of linux. See [Internet/ConnectionSharing](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing)
 - [Ubuntu - CommunityHelpWiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CommunityHelpWiki).

You can also use one wifi device as both an ap and client. See [Raspberry Pi Zero W Simultaneous AP and Managed Mode Wifi](https://albeec13.github.io/2017/09/26/raspberry-pi-zero-w-simultaneous-ap-and-managed-mode-wifi/)