# Wireless client and software AP with a single Wi-Fi device, with Ubuntu

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

[This article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/software_access_point#Wireless_client_and_software_AP_with_a_single_Wi-Fi_device) about ArchLinux indicates the possibility to setup WLAN client and soft-AP using a single physical WiFi device on a host. Wondering if this configuration is possible on Ubuntu as well ? If so, can someone verify and guide if the steps are same ?

I did find these other AskUbuntu Q&As (including [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot)) that are clearly relevant, but do not cover the aspect of ***simultaneous client and soft-AP*** type of usage. Also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/663956/wifi-hotspot-software-package-other-than-ap-hotspot) talks of the tool on Ubuntu to setup soft-AP, but doesn't answer the part about simultaneous use in 2 modes.

**Clarification-edit:**
*Kindly note that my question is not about an alternative to a soft-AP setup tool like `ap-hotspot` but, how to assign/configure dual roles i.e. soft-AP and WLAN-client, on same host, using same WLAN device.*

Comment: Please see the clarification provided.

Comment: This question already has an answer here:[How do I create a WiFi hotspot sharing wireless internet connection (single adapter)?](https://askubuntu.com/a/324785/723193). It depends on if your hardware supports the necessary combination of modes, [see](https://superuser.com/a/1036048)